# Is there a way to check substring existence in PowerBI DAX Studio or SSIS for a DAX Expression in a measure?

Tags: sql, ssis, powerbi, dax, mdx

I was using SSIS / DAX Studio and I extracted all measures from PowerBI published dataset using a following code:

```
select 
    MEASURE_NAME as MeasureName
    ,MEASUREGROUP_NAME as TableName
    ,TRIM(EXPRESSION) as DAXExpression
    from $system.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
```

and as a result I get all my measures created in PowerBI model with their table names and dax expressions. The problem I'm facing now is basically about searching a particular **Substring** within results I got. Precisely, within *DAXExpression* column. So I tried to use *contains*, *containsstring* and *search* functions however always the result is like *Error: An unknown DMX expression was encountered at line X, column Y.*

I need to extract list of all measures containing **SUM** in their DAX Expressions. Does anyone know how can I do this via DAX Studio or SQL Server Management Studio?

The following code is not working, and it's variants with mentioned above functions doesn't work as well.

```
select
    MEASURE_NAME as MeasureName
    ,MEASUREGROUP_NAME as TableName
    ,TRIM(EXPRESSION) as DAXExpression
    
    from $system.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
    where MEASURE_NAME LIKE "%SUM%" // not working
    order by MEASUREGROUP_NAME
```

Comment: While I love StackOverflow I have to say that for DAX questions I have found more help on https://community.powerbi.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

You can use TabularEditor and C# script.
After you install TabularEditor; just open your Powerbi Model -> go to External Tools:
[image]

> using System.IO;
>
> string folder = @"C:\Users\mstaszak\Downloads\";   string fileName =
> "MesuresWithSUM.txt";
>
> var list = new List ();
>
> foreach (Measure m in Model.AllMeasures) {
> if(m.Expression.Contains("SUM"))  {
> list.Add(m.Name);
> } }
>
> string fullPath = folder + fileName;   File.WriteAllLines(fullPath,
> list);   list.Output();

Put this script here and run:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's working partially - I can see a list of formulas due to a line `list.Output();` however saving to a file is not working on my end. I may have done something wrong here, as I am not too familiar with C# but just looking at the code it seems like there's no bug (I should say: there's no warning or error).

Comment: Did you change path in "folder" variable to correct one for you? 
List.Output(); should give us popup window with measures name, while line 22
file.WriteAllLines(FullPath, list); should generete file

Comment: folder should have "\" at the end